# Why were two questions about Entity Framework deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

Is there hate for Entity Framework? Two questions about how to get the SQL command from Entity Framework were deleted on 26 August, both having previously been closed on 13 August with the "questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved" reason.

They are both quite old: [The first one is dated September 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework), and [the other one is dated January 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700323/how-to-get-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework).

(I found one of the two when googling for the same thing; I received a link to one of the two and from there there was a link to the other one.)

Comment: Dunno about the first one, but the answers to the second one are pretty worthless. It could be seen as attracting link-only answers.

Comment: Someone was bumping questions by copying and pasting the same answer across them. Don't know why they would trigger question deletion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted those both, so I suppose I'm the best to answer this!

As [BoltClock](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn) noted, both got bumped due to being answered with a copy-paste answer. There was a flag for multiple duplicate answers which lead me to the posts, where I closed them (after taking action on the duplicated answers).

I marked them as favorites to check back on them later, which I apparently did yesterday. I deleted them based on the quality of the questions in relation to the fact that they had been closed. (I don't unilaterally delete posts like this which are still 'On-Hold', but only if they've actually graduated to 'closed')

When I delete questions like these, I usually try to ignore the answers completely, and I try to apply a "what should happen to this question if it's posted today?" thought process to it.

That said, I think that first question *might* be worth talking about keeping around, solely on the basis of its answers... but something makes me feel a little bit icky there. I think the question seems to have been fine for the standards when it was posted, but today? Today, the biggest controversy over that question would be, "can't we be nicer to newbies than just telling them to RTFM?"

---

I've undeleted the first one. I think it could be improved to make it a decent question even for today, but I also suspect there's something else out there that would apply, [such as this clumsily-worded Google search's second result](https://www.google.com/search?q=entity+framework+get+sql+executed&oq=entity+framework+get+sql+executed&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.9642j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Finally, one tiny mitigating point to mention: There were two weeks between closing and deleting, and right before that, the questions had been bumped by the c/p answer, so there was time for the community to review it, too.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but I acted on a flag for the second one and undeleted it as well (without seeing this discussion). I marked it as a duplicate of the first, to at least point Google traffic in a good direction. I admit I'm not a subject matter expert, though, so I may have missed something here.

Comment: @BradLarson Of course I don't mind. I'd actually considered doing just that!